# Is it posible for an android user to set up a work and personal profile and isolate whatsapp to personal profile

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, profiles, sandboxing

With the new GDPR regulations in Europe I see people freaking out and deleting whatsapp from their phone. I don't wish to get into the legal details of if this is legally necessary or not. However this seems only to apply to people using their personal phone for business purposes.

My question is, can you create two profiles for android. One for business and the other personal. Each profile should come with it's own address book / contacts list. Then the next question is, is it possible to sandbox Whatsapp to only use/see the personal address list and not the business one.

Is this

(1) Possible

(2) Easy to do for the non technical user ?

Comment: Related: [Installing Applications in Isolated Environments](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177905/209414)

Comment: Also I think what you describe works better if work vice-versa (i.e isolating Whatsapp to "work/island" profile. But will have to hear from you and I won'd be taking down the answer until I get this feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  You can do that with [Island](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.island&hl=en) (and the released **official version**) is now available on Google playstore.

*"Island" is a sandbox environment to clone selected apps and isolate them from accessing your personal data outside the sandbox (including call logs, contacts, photos and etc) even if related permissions are granted. Device-bound data is still accessible (SMS, IMEI and etc).*

**How does it work**

> Island takes advantage of the "managed profile" feature on Android
>   5.0+, which is the also the base of "Android for Work", to create an isolated sandbox for apps and their data. App needs to be cloned in
>   Island first. Afterwards, the clone can run parallel aside from the
>   original one. (even with different accounts signed-in) It can be
>   frozen on demand by Island. (NO ROOT REQUIRED)

[image] [image]

The goal of Island to improve security by isolating an application thus improving privacy at the same time allowing parallel running with those from "mainland"